# Javafx - ListView - Text of nodes defined in the fxml file disappear when I click on one item

Tags: java, listview, javafx

Hello I have a listview that must display products, but when I click on an item, the text of the nodes defined in the fxml file disappear, (we can see the outline of the link, but the text disappear). What is the problem please?

Result :

[Normal.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9tlP.png)
[WhenIClick.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sgkS.png)

CellProduct.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;

public class CellProduct extends ListCell<Product> {

private HBox cellView;
private ProductCellController productCellController;

public CellProduct() {
    super();
    FXMLLoader PRODUCT_CELL_FXML_LOADER = LoaderFile.getFXMLLoader("ProductCellView");
    cellView = (HBox) LoaderFile.loadView(PRODUCT_CELL_FXML_LOADER);
    productCellController = PRODUCT_CELL_FXML_LOADER.getController();
    System.out.println(productCellController);
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(Product product, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(product, empty);

    if (product == null || empty) {
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        String urlImage = product.getUrlImage();
        double price = product.getPrice();
        String name = product.getName();
        String shortDescription = product.getShortDescription();
        String rating = String.valueOf(product.getRating());
        String numberOpinion = String.valueOf(product.getNumberOpinion());
        StateProduct state = product.getState();
        productCellController.init(urlImage, name, shortDescription, rating, numberOpinion, state);

        setGraphic(cellView);
        setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("Click"));
      }
   } 
}
```

LoaderFile.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;

public class LoaderFile {
private class ClassForGetClass {}
public static FXMLLoader getFXMLLoader(String nameView) {
    return new FXMLLoader(ClassForGetClass.class.getResource(nameView + ".fxml"));
}

public static Node loadView(FXMLLoader fXMLLoader) {
    try {
        return fXMLLoader.load();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
       }
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main (String[] args ) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<Product> listView = new ListView<Product>();

        Scene scene = new Scene(listView, 900, 500);
        Product product = new Product(1,"http://media.ldlc.com/ld/products/00/04/10/90/LD0004109014_2_0004109423_0004109488.jpg", false, 2000.0, "MSI GS63VR 7RF-262FR Stealth Pro 4K", "PC PORTABLE", "",2, 2.5, StateProduct.IN_STOCK, "", 1, "", 1);
        for (int index = 0; index < 30; index++) {
            listView.getItems().add(product);
        }

        listView.setCellFactory(param -> {
            System.out.println("Création d'une cellule");
            return new CellProduct();
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Product.java

```
    public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String urlImage;
    private boolean isSelected;
    private double price;
    private String name;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String longDescription;
    private int numberOpinion;
    private double rating;
    private StateProduct state;
    private String domain;
    private int domainID;
    private String category;
    private int categoryID;

    public Product(int id, String urlImage, boolean isSelected, double price, String name, String shortDescription, String longDescription, int numberOpinion, double rating, StateProduct state, String domain, int domainID, String category, int categoryID) {
        this.id = id;
        this.urlImage = urlImage;
        this.isSelected = isSelected;
        this.price = price;
        this.name = name;
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
        this.longDescription = longDescription;
        this.numberOpinion = numberOpinion;
        this.rating = rating;
        this.state = state;
        this.domain = domain;
        this.domainID = domainID;
        this.category = category;
        this.categoryID = categoryID;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getUrlImage() {
        return urlImage;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return isSelected;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    public String getLongDescription() {
        return longDescription;
    }

    public int getNumberOpinion() {
        return numberOpinion;
    }

    public double getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public StateProduct getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }

    public int getDomainID() {
        return domainID;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public int getCategoryID() {
        return categoryID;
    }
}
```

ProductCellController.java

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class ProductCellController {
    @FXML private Hyperlink nameProductHyperLink;
    @FXML private CheckBox checkBoxProductCompare;
    @FXML private Label priceLabel;
    @FXML private ImageView productImageView;
    @FXML private Label descriptionProductLabel;
    @FXML private Label numberOpinionLabel;
    @FXML private VBox stateProductVBox;
    @FXML private Button addBasketButton;

    public void init(String urlImageProduct, String nameProduct, String descriptionProduct, String ratingProduct, String numberOpinion, StateProduct stateProduct) {
        // productImageView.setImage(new Image(urlImageProduct));
        productImageView.setImage(new Image("Laptop.png"));
        nameProductHyperLink.setText(nameProduct);
        descriptionProductLabel.setText(descriptionProduct);
        numberOpinionLabel.setText(numberOpinion + " Avis");
        priceLabel.setText("2000.00 $");

        String color = stateProduct.getColor();

        stateProductVBox.getChildren().clear(); // reset else old labels are not deleted, it is normal ?
        for (String string: stateProduct.getPartiesName()) {
            Label label = new Label(string);
            String style = "-fx-text-fill : " + color + "; -fx-font-weight: bold; -fx-font-size: 14px;"; // -fx-text-fill ne fonctionne pas avec les { }
            label.setStyle(style);
            stateProductVBox.getChildren().add(label);
        }

        addBasketButton.setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image("AddShoppingCart.png")));
        addBasketButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> System.out.println("click"));
    }
}
```

StateProduct.java

```
    public enum StateProduct {
    IN_STOCK("EN-STOCK", "#15AA15"),
    BREAKING("RUPTURE", "#737373"),
    AVAILABLE_SUPPLIER("DISPO-FOURNISSEUR", "#062D8F"),
    WITHIN_7_DAYS("SOUS-7 JOURS", "#FFB502"),
    WITHIN_7_AND_15__DAYS("ENTRE-7/15 JOURS", "#FF6400"),
    MORE_THAN_15_DAYS("+ DE-15 JOURS", "#FF0606");

    private String[] partiesName;
    private String color;

    StateProduct(String partiesName, String color) {
        this.partiesName = partiesName.split("-");
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String[] getPartiesName() {
        return partiesName;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.join(" ", partiesName);
    }
}
```

[Laptop.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3OSr.png)
[AddShoppingCart.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzuAl.png)

Comment: This is probably more source code than we need and makes answering your question harder rather than easier. Where do you think the issue is most likely to be coming from?

Comment: Sorry, I posted all the code needed to run the code, I thought it was going to be easier to help me with that. The problem is that when I add an element in the java code the text does not disappear, however when it is a widget defined in the fxml file it disappears. I do not know if it's a bug, or did I forget a step in creating the cell.

Comment: I add images showing the problems in the post

Comment: You should create and post a [MCVE]. This is certainly not minimal, because there is functionality here not related to the problem, and it's not complete either, because we can't run it.

Comment: That said, I think that what is happening is that you have the labels in the graphic in the cell contained inside some container that doesn't set `-fx-background` in its CSS. When you select a cell, the cell sets `-fx-background` to the selection color. That property is inherited and causes any text to adjust to something contrasting it, so you end up with very light text on a very light background. It looks like you are using some CSS on the graphic for the cell that is not compatible with the way the default CSS works.

Comment: I guess I should clarify slight inaccuracies in my previous comment. `-fx-background` is not a property, but a looked-up color (so it is inherited if it is set by a parent node, and it's set in `Cell`). Text inside a control that defines or inherits `-fx-background` has, by default, text fill that depends on `-fx-background`. By default, the *property* `-fx-background-color` is set to the *looked-up color* `-fx-background`. Note that the green text (which I assume you get by setting `-fx-text-fill` on it) doesn't disappear, because it loses its default "depend on `-fx-background`" value.